What's the reason behind Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits?
Ok, I get that two fundamental circuit laws, which are KCL and KVL, are because of conservation of charge and because of conservation of energy in electrical circuits.
Now I want to relate this to "Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits". Why can I in linear circuits choose two ports and find their "Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits"?

conservation of energy? how so?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні yeah. the reason for KVL is the law of conversation of energy in physics.

There is no necessary conservation of charge or energy when it comes to Norton and Thevenin equivalent circuits except at the port terminals. This means you can't relate Norton and Thevenin equivalent circuits the way you want to. Anything internal to either the Norton or Thevenin model will not be equivalent in energy or charge.
Consider a black box that produces 1 volt into an open-circuit and has a short-circuit current of 1 amp. The Thevenin model will be a 1 volt source in series with a 1 Ω resistor and dissipate no internal power when unloaded. However, the Norton model will be a 1 amp source in parallel with a 1 Ω resistor and dissipate 1 watt of internal power when unloaded. On the other hand, when shorted, the Thevenin model will dissipate 1 watt whilst the Norton model will dissipate no power.
Both produce the same characteristic voltages and currents at the port when loaded but, internally they are totally different.

so can we say Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuiits only care that you get X volts voltage and Y amps current at your terminals. and for having that, you need a voltage or current source (producing energy) and a resistor / impedance (consuming energy), so you'll have Vth / In and Zth / Zn. am i right?

@Neotod Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits produce identical open circuit voltages and, identical short-circuit currents and, are electrically indistinguishable from each other at their two respective terminals under all identical loading conditions. Anything else to say about them is based on what I've just said.

If you have a black box with two output terminals, you can determine what the source voltage and output impedance of those terminals are.
But there are almost infinitely many ways it can be implemented, as long as the implementation matches the observation.

"you can determine what the source voltage and output impedance of those terminals are." ok but for this, you should use Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits. but imagine i don't know this.

@Neotod You don't need them. You only need to measure open-circuit voltage, say 1V, and short-circuit current, say 1mA, basically with a multimeter. And you then have a simple model of the equivalent circuit, being an 1V supply in series with 1kohm output impedance. However, in real life, infinitely many combinations of source voltages and resistive divider networks can lead to same apparent result of 1V open circuit voltage and 1mA short circuit current, meaning 1kohm output impedance.
